# Property 'elements' does not exist on type union with HTMLFormElement

Tags: typescript, union-types

This error appears when trying to destructure an `form.elements` object.

`Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement | HTMLFormElement'.
  Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

```
// in a class

domRefs: {[key: string]: HTMLFormElement | HTMLElement | null} = {
  myForm: null
}

onButtonClick = () => {
  const {a, b, c} = this.domRefs.myForm!.elements
}
```

I specified the `HTMLFormElement` earlier and it's also more specific type than `HTMLElement`, why it isn't being properly recognized?

Using `HTMLFormElement & HTMLElement` did work for this particular case, but is it the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

If your element type defined using union types, to access the type specific properties of an element in typescript you should check element type first.

```
if (this.domRefs.myForm instanceof HTMLFormElement) {
    // Your code specific for HTMLFormElement here
}
```

"Using HTMLFormElement & HTMLElement" in this way you tell to the compiler that your element has all the features that defined in both types. But in your case this is completely useless because HTMLFormElement extends HTMLElement and it is already has all its features.

P.S. More about types you can read [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).